# why for any C array this expression holds a[7] == 7[a]

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Can anyone explain me why for any array the expression c `a[7] == 7[a]` is true.

is there any case that it can be false

I have seen in wiki that x[i] is a syntactic sugar for *(x+i) and this is equal to *(i+x) and this is i[x], but I can not understand this properly.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question is about 5, this one is about 7. :)

Comment: Before searching on SO, consider checking the excellent [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `a[7]` is equivalent to `*(a + 7)`.
- Similarly `7[a]` is equivalent to `*(7 + a)`.

This gives the same result because adding an integer to a pointer is a [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) operation.

---

> is there any case that it can be false

The short answer is no. For simple pointer arithmetic it will always be true.

The long answer is that to find a counterexample you would have to use a hack. One way you could do it is to use a macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define a 1+s

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "1q2w3e4r5t6y";
    int x = a[7];
    int y = 7[a];
    printf("%c %c\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
s 5
```

The result is different because after the macro expansion the expressions become different: `1+(s[7])` versus `7[1+s]`.

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/364lK6)

Answer (score 0):

a[7] gets translated to *(a+7) & 7[a] gets translated to *(7+a), which refer to same location & thus same data.

Answer (score 0):

`I have seen in wiki that x[i] is a syntactic sugar for *(x+i) and this is equal to *(i+x) and this is i[x], but I can not understand this properly.`

It's Simple `pointer arithmetic` and addition is `commutative`. (so I don't think there should be any problem to understand)

see this...

```
a[7] == *(a+7) == *(7+a) == 7[a]
```

`a+7` is `7+a` because addition operation is commutative.

Hence `a[7] == 7[a]` , proved